# why URL Query string appears in middle of hostname and the path name.... Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm learning VueJs,and i want to develop a register page, but I think something is wrong here, I have a click event to submit the data and when I click in the button to submit it, I print the data in the console, and what I have noticed is the query string is in the middle of hostname and path name, and I dont know if that is normal.

This is how URL looks like:

http://localhost:8080/?email=asas%40mail.com&password=asdsa#/register

This is some of my code:

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import home from './components/home'
import register from './components/register'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
 routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: home
    },
    {
      path: '/register/',
      name: 'register',
      component: register
    }
  ]
})
```

Register.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" v- 
                               model="email">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" 
                               v-model="password">
        <button v-on:click="clickRegister">Submit form</button>
       </form>
     </div>    
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
           email:'',
           password:''
      }
   },
    methods:{
        clickRegister: function() {
            console.log(this.email)
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
       <router-view></router-view>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {

 }
</script>


<style>

</style>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './registerServiceWorker'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: function (h) { return h(App) }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal behavior as the default behavior for a SPA in Vue is to use the # to route your application.

The query string is actually not before your path, it's shown before the anchor which contains a path.

You can get rid of the # and rely on the browser history instead and therefore use a normal path by setting your router to use the history mode :

```
export default new Router({
 mode: 'history',
 routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: home
    },
    {
      path: '/register/',
      name: 'register',
      component: register
    }
  ]
})
```

Source : https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: thank you for your answer i thought that, string query should be after '/register' like this:     http://localhost:8080/register?email=asas%40mail.com&password=asdsa#

Comment: yup afer I change to mode: history the query string shows after '/register'... thankyou again

Comment: No problem, glad you got this sorted out !